# Zend Framework 2 - Magic Getter and Setter for Doctrine and Annotation forms

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-db, magic-methods

I read about a magic getter- and setter function which supersede the huge plie of standard getters and setters. ([Link](http://milesj.me/blog/read/minimal-class-getset))

I altered the function of Miles because I'm using `AnnotationForms` and don't want the underscore in the variables like `$_name`. I updated the magic functions but when trying to call e.g. `getName()` I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ... Entity::getName()

Here's my code:

```
<?php
namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\Form\Annotation as Form;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="masterdata_entity")
 * @Form\Name("entity")
 * @Form\Attributes({ "class": "form-horizontal" })
 * @Form\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
*/
class Entity
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   * @Form\Exclude()
   */
  protected $id;
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
   * @Form\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":50}})
   * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
   * @Form\Options({"label":"Name"})
   */
  protected $name;

public function __get($property) {
    return (isset($this->{$property}) ? $this->{$property} : null);
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
    if (isset($this->{$property})) {
        $this->{$property} = $value;
    }
}

public function __isset($property) {
    return isset($this->{$property});
}

}
```

Any ideas why that is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Provide your Entities code, please

Comment: that's the part that's needed :D Actually, what's just coming to my mind, i think the hydrators do not work with magic functions. They need the actual getters and setters to be callable. Iirc, they check for function_exists

Comment: See updated comment, but i'll check it, too

Comment: You need to define the `__set()` and `__get()` magic methods. This is not a Zend or Doctrine approach either, it's [built into PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess my comment was right. Checking the [DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php#L68), you will see that it basically uses the [\Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php). Taking a look at the `extract()`-function you can see that all ClassMethods will be fetched at [line #60](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php#L60)

```
$methods = get_class_methods($object);
```

And taking a look at [line #63++](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php#L63-L65) you will see that only default getters `getX, hasX, isX` are to be seen as valid:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(get|has|is)[A-Z]\w*/', $method)) {
    continue;
}
```

This ultimately means, that you will always have to write your setters and getters. Even though the filesize may become a little bit bigger. It is better for usual IDEs and it is a performance boost, too, even despite filesize.

Comment: thanks. Having my own setters implemented I get this error when editing a variable: `Fatal error: Cannot access protected property`. My attributes are protected as it is shown in nearly every example... any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Of course, you are using `\Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty`. Since you are using DoctrineEntities, the correct Hydrator to be used would be `\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject`

Comment: thanks... but now i get the following: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given, called in ...\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\Factory.php on line 566 and defined in ...\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-module\src\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject.php on line 63`. and my doctrine version should be set to at least v2.1

Comment: Ah yeah, about that, erm...  The DoctrineObject-Hydrator needs the ObjectManager/EntityManager as parameter. I have no clue how to achieve this using AnnotationForms. Maybe try using the ClassMethods Hydrator. It may work, too, but i really don't know about AnnotationForms too much. I create the forms by hand

Comment: i opened a new issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055669/zend-framework-2-annotation-forms-and-doctrine2-catchable-fatal-error-obje