# Zend Framework 2 - Annotation forms and Doctrine2 - Catchable fatal error - ObjectManager

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm using Zend, Doctrine2.1 and AnnotationForms.

My entity looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="myentity")
 * @Form\Name("myentity")
 * @Form\Attributes({ "class": "form-horizontal" })
 * @Form\Hydrator("\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject")
*/
class MyEntity {
   ...
}
```

When using this `DoctrineObject` I get the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given, called in C:\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\Factory.php on line 566 and defined in C:\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-module\src\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject.php on line 63

I cannot use `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty` because then I get

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property

I'm quite lost. Anybody an idea what I can do to fix this issue?

I'm guessing that I need a `__construct()` function. But what do I put in there?

Comment: 1) Can you confirm you instantiate the form through the `FormElementManager` service? 2) Have you tried registering the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` as a factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone may come up with a Annotation-only function, if that exists, meanwhile you can go this approach:

```
$form = //create the annotation form WITHOUT a hydrator
$objectManager = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$hydrator = new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject($objectManager);
$form->setHydrator($hydrator);

//continue in your controller
```

Comment: get the same error. maybe i took the wrong servicelocator? where do you get it from?

Comment: On controller-scope this would be `$this->getServiceLocator()` - but if that doesn't work, i think my approach won't work at all. As mentioned: not knowledgable enough on annotationforms after all :S

Comment: Well, that's exactly what i said in my answer :D See the comment at line #1 :P

Comment: the thing is: when i leave the hydrator out, everything works just fine. why do i need it then, anyway?

Comment: It's the hydrators job to properly extract and hydrate data in and out of objects. Try updating an object without a hydrator, i'd be surprised if it worked. Maybe though it falls back to classmethods anyways so... :)

Comment: it works. but i'll stick to this hydrator if you say its supposed to be used. never work against the framework ;)

Comment: This is a known doctrine/zf issue, for a solution working with annotations (using factory) see the issue discussion: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

Had also problems with the annotation forms. My solution was a mindbreaker. Took me long time to find out. 
My problem was in the first line of the annotation code.

```
/**
```

This line is normally used for commenting your annotation code, but allmost everybody leaves it empty. Normally no issues, but this is somehow causing problems in the form annotations. You should either add some comment, add a space, or move your first line of code up. So:

```
/** Some comment to make this annotation work
/** (<-- a space)
```

or start like this:

```
/** @ORM\Entity
```

Don't ask me why this is happening (some parsing error?). I found this on a post on GitHub where someone reported having similar issue (https://github.com/doctrine/common/issues/331). As I understood the bug is not a doctrine but a ZF2 issue and it has been reported.

Not sure this is your issue as well, but posting this was the least i could do...

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at [this solution](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/102), it's preatty good

Comment: Maybe you should explain the solution a bit more, in case the link breaks down at some point.